# Able to render video to MUX in GraphEdit but get VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT in code

Tags: c++, directshow

I am trying to get the 3ivxfilters working in my C++ Directshow application and it continually fails to connect the 3IVX Video Encoder output pin to the 3IVX Media Muxer input pin. I always get the error VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT.

All filters have been added to the graph by enumerating the monikers so there shouldn't be any issue due to adding using a CLSID directly.

When I open the graph via graph edit and right click / choose render on the Video Encoder output pin it works fine.

Here is my code for connecting the filter:

```
    HRESULT ConnectFilters(IGraphBuilder *pGraph, IBaseFilter *pSrc, IBaseFilter *pDest)
{
    IPin *pOut = NULL;

    // Find an output pin on the first filter.
    HRESULT hr = FindUnconnectedPin(pSrc, PINDIR_OUTPUT, &pOut);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ConnectFilters(pGraph, pOut, pDest);
        pOut->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Basically once it finds the appropriate pins it uses the Connect method.

```
            hr = pGraph->Connect(pOut, pIn);
```

Comment: _When I open the graph via graph edit and right click / choose render on the Video Encoder output pin it works fine._ - Then why not use `IGraphBuilder::Render` instead of `Connect`?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried Render on the output pin of the encoder and get this error - VFW_E_NO_VP_HARDWARE (No video port hardware is available, or the hardware is not responding.)

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion for this? I'm really stuck here.

Comment: @JustinC Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No.  Unfortunately it is only supported with older versions of visual Studio. I couldn't get it to work with directshow.  They were very helpful and investigated.  They reproduced the issue but it was not cost effective for them to fix it.